# How to add glyphicons to rails link_to helper - Bootstrap 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I've been looking everywhere for a good explanation of how to add glyphicons to rails `link_to` and `button_to` helpers, but I've found very little. What I've gathered so far has led me to this:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to deals_path, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
    <%= content_tag(:i, "Dasboard",:class=>' glyphicon, glyphicon-th-large') -%>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

This doesn't work though and I think the one example I found was from Bootstrap 2. Can anyone point me to a good resource on this, or provide a quick example? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 109, accepted):

I found the answer to this [here](https://coderwall.com/p/xnxnpw)

The basic form of a glyph link in rails looks like this:

```
<%= link_to deals_path, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></i> Dashboard
<% end %>
```

Modify as needed. The second example in that link didn't work for me, I assume because I'm using the rails_bootstrap_sass gem? Regardless, the above form worked for me.

Answer (score 28):

If you're looking for an inline method, This works for me:

```
<%= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></i> Dasboard'.html_safe, deals_path, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
```

The `<i></i>` can go either side of the `'Dashboard'` I've only tested this particular example out in Rails 4 with Bootstrap 3 but this was the method I used prior in Rails 3 and Bootstrap 2

Hope this helps somebody in the future

Edit: Removed comma to render the glyphicon correctly.

Comment: After upgrading to rails 4 from 3 this inline solution fixed my broken links that were previously setup in the do...end format.

Answer (score 18):

In my experience the answer by @settheline is almost ideal, but on my website it changes the font relative to other buttons without icons. So I ended up doing something like this:

```
<%= link_to deals_path, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span> Dashboard
<% end %>
```

And this seems to keep the font equal to other iconless buttons.

Comment: Found this today after some time - if you're having rails issues applying the glyphicon class along with a button class from bootstrap then this is the answer you've been looking for!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using slim, here's `link_to`:

```
    = link_to deals_path
        span.glyphicon.glyphicon-th-large
```

and `button_to`:

```
    = button_to deals_path, class: "btn btn-primary"
        span.glyphicon.glyphicon-th-large
```

It's possible to add more text/etc. to the button as well, just don't nest it under the glyphicon's span.

Answer (score 2):

Using HAML:

```
= link_to deals_path, class: "btn btn-default" do
  = "Dashboard"
  %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-th-large
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `font-awesome-rails` gem for this purpose, and then do:

```
<li><%= link_to raw(fa_icon("dashboard", class: "th-large"), deals_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

Comment: Hmmm...I've got font-awesome-rails going, but not sure where the comma's are supposed to go in here. Looks like you're either missing one on the end, or have an extra one after `fa_icon`?

Comment: After further searching, I don't need font-awesome to use Bootstrap glyphs. I answered above.

Answer (score 1):

&For those who'd avoid unnecessary repetition of the long-winded thing..

i shove something like this in my `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def glyph(icon_name_postfix, hash={})
    content_tag :span, nil, hash.merge(class: "glyphicon glyphicon-#{icon_name_postfix.to_s.gsub('_','-')}")
  end
end
```

Example `.erb` usage:

```
<%= button_tag glyph("heart-empty", aria_hidden: "true", foo: "bar"), type: "button", class: "btn btn-default" %>
<%= link_to glyph(:eye_open) + " Oook", some_path, class: "nav" %>
```

I am using this in `Rails4` but i think it might also work in `Rails3`

Ooook! i also happened to notice this advise from the bootstrap (Currently v3.3.5) [docos](http://getbootstrap.com/components/):

> **Don't mix with other components** Icon classes cannot be directly combined with other components. They should not be used along with
>   other classes on the same element. Instead, add a nested `<span>` and
>   apply the icon classes to the `<span>`.
>
> **Only for use on empty elements** Icon classes should only be used on elements that contain no text content and have no child elements.

Answer (score -1):

### There is faster and easier way to apply (fontawasome) icons without additional gem installations.

You may follow this pattern:

```
          <%= link_to root_path, class: "nav-link" do %>
            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
          <% end %>
```

Of course, you must first create a kit FREE account from the FONTAWASOME and it must be set in your `application.html.erb`'s **head** to use the icons.
Follow the instructions given here to [create an account in Fontawasome](https://fontawesome.com/start) (if you don't have one yet).

If you need an example, you can check out my repo in [GitHub](https://github.com/SarvarKh/travellers)

Comment: I am quite sure, proposed way is better solution, isn't it? If you have any comment or it didn't work for you, I would be glad to help you. Please leave your comments below. I will try to help when I have a chance.