# Add bootstrap glyph icon to link_to with multiple arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've been using glyphicons with Bootstrap for a few weeks with no problems. However now I'm using link_to with more arguments and I can't put the "do" in the proper place to get things working error free.

I have implemented my basic link_to's like the following example with no problem: [How to add glyphicons to rails link_to helper - Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694997/how-to-add-glyphicons-to-rails-link-to-helper-bootstrap-3)

Here's my code:

```
<%= link_to("Start Task", task_path(task, "task[started_at]" => DateTime.now), :method => :put, :confirm => "Sure?", class: "btn btn-default btn-sm") %>
```

I sincerely appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use link_to with a block as stated in the [link_to documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

> You can use a block as well if your link target is hard to fit into the name parameter.

```
<%= link_to(task_path(task, "task[started_at]" => DateTime.now), :method => :put, :confirm => "Sure?", class: "btn btn-default btn-sm") do |link| %>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i> Start Task
<% end %>
```

Comment: You should elaborate on your answer and explain your code.

Comment: Readers should understand *why* they should use your code. So a small sentence to it, maybe with a link to the documentation, will help them.

Comment: @SebastianZartner You're right, have added a link to the docs and a small explanation.

Comment: I found an answer at about the same time but your solution is much cleaner. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the following link and made the necessary adjustments: [Adding a Twitter Bootstrap button icon to button_to in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468094/adding-a-twitter-bootstrap-button-icon-to-button-to-in-rails?rq=1)

```
<%= link_to raw("<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-play\"></i> Start"), task_path(task, "task[started_at]" => DateTime.now), :method => :put, :confirm => "Sure?", class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" %>
```