# Glyphicon link_to not behaving as expected in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, glyphicons

I've created a sidebar menu that expand out when a button is pressed

I've tried to attached glyphicons but it shows the expanded view by default. How can I get the expected behaviour as per the example?

http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/YJB4q/11/

Here is an example part of my code

```
<li> <a class='expandable' href='#' title='MyChallenges'>
            <%= link_to discovers_path, class: "btn" do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span>
            <% end %>
            <span class='expanded-element'>Discover</span>
          </a>
```

Comment: why are you adding link_to within anchor tag. link_to is also anchor tag.

Comment: Fair enough. I've removed it but still have the same problem

Comment: replace this `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span>` with this `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></i>`

Comment: I get the same problem @Athar

Comment: what is it showing.?

Comment: this is similar to your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694997/how-to-add-glyphicons-to-rails-link-to-helper-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error this is what worked for me

```
<li> 
          <%= link_to ' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open collapsed-element"></span><span class="expanded-element">Discover</span>'.html_safe, discovers_path, class: 'expandable' %>
          </li>
```

My mistake was to not realise that the link_to actually generates the `<a></a>` tags